# Is my Guadia Quest save independent of the actual "Game" save?

Tags: retro-game-challenge

I've recently unlocked the game "Guadia Quest" while playing Retro Game Challenge, and it is the first game to feature an independent save feature (Retro Game Challenge itself consists of a collection of unlockable games, and only Guadia Quest has save functionality built into the game within the game).

I was wondering whether saving the game in Guadia Quest is sufficient for me to be able to resume it later, or if I have to perform an actual save in the game itself afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having simply tried it out, I can now say for certain that the Guadia Quest save is completely independent of Retro Gaming Challenge's save.